# Shuffling Multiple arrays Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, shuffle

I need to shuffle multiple arrays using the same function so that it randomizes the words up in each sentence.

Using HTML i then need a button that starts the shuffle, with the outputted sentences with line break between each for example:

```
var array1 = ["The, "Man", "and", "his", "dog"];
var array2 = ["went", "for", "a", "walk", "outside"];
```

On click of a button "shuffle" im trying to get the output to display on seperate lines like this:

Man and dog his the

for a outside walk went

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array

Comment: This is a question and answer site. There is no question here nor is there any mention of problems you are having trying to accomplish your goal. All you have provided is a goal and this is also not a free code writing service

Comment: You've asked the same question (only with different array content) yesterday: [Trying to shuffle multiple arrays in javascript but in the same way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43281492/trying-to-shuffle-multiple-arrays-in-javascript-but-in-the-same-way)

Comment: @AB1412, it is working for you ?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `map` and `sort` methods.

First of all, you can generate a random number for every item in the array, using `Math.random` method. Next step is to sort array by this `generated` number.

Last step is to create the sentence with the items of the array, using `join` method.

```js
var array1 = ["The", "Man", "and", "his", "dog"];
console.log(array1.map(function(n){ 
              return [Math.random(), n];
            }).sort().map(function(item){
                return item[1] ;
           }).join(' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you....

```js
["The", "Man", "and", "his", "dog"]
      .map(w => { return { seq: Math.random(), word: w } })
        .sort((a,b) => a.seq<b.seq?-1:1)
          .map(w => w.word)
```